# How can I send a message parameter to spring login page using a query param?

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I want to send a message to be displayed on login page. I was thinking to use a query param, something like `myapp/login?m=4` and then handle this param in controller, but it seems that I am redirected back to myapp/login.

Any idea which is the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ModelMap in controller to send message to JSP page like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/index" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hi, Welcome to mysite. ");
    return "login";
}
```

in login.jsp you can use model attribute like below :

```
<body>
    Greeting : ${greeting}
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Prakash, but wasn't this what I actually wanted. I want to redirect user to login, and pass message like parameter. Something like `url=myapp/login?m=23` 

`@RequestMapping(value = { "/index" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage(ModelMap model @RequestParam long m) {
    String message=findMessage(m); 
   model.addAttribute("message",  message);
    return "login";
}`

Comment: you can use @PathVariable like @RequestMapping(value = { "/index/{m}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String homePage(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("m") long m) { 
String message=findMessage(m); 
model.addAttribute("message", message); 
return "login"; 
}

Comment: Now your url will be like url=myapp/index/23

Comment: I get the same result. I think something should be changed in security configuration. Not it's like
`.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")` 
How should I configure it to accept parameters? 
I mapped controller like:
`@RequestMapping("/login/{m}") `

Comment: *Now it's like instead of Not it's like. Seems the edit time expired.